# Negative impact of "important" features on model performance

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, random-forest, optimization

I have a random forest regressor with a set of base features, fit & optimised with sklearn random search algorithm. When I add a set of additional features and retrain (again with random search optimisation) the model performance becomes worse.

Afterwards, I use multiple algorithms to determine the feature importance of all features - recursive feature elimination (RFE), built-in RF feature importance, permutation importance. Some of the newly added features actually show a high importance (with all algorithms).

**So how can it be that features, which show high importance actually reduce the model performance (significantly)?** I could not yet find any satisfying answer to this problem (or misunderstanding of mine).

Comment: When you say model performance do you refer to train, val or test scores?

Comment: Actually all. Train, Val and Test. Metric used is Mean Absolute Error